# Accidently deleted *.so files in extensions folder at /usr/lib/php5

Tags: php

This might sound really stupid.

But, While developing a PHP extension I accidently deleted all *.so files in extensions folder(named as a long number) located at /usr/lib/php5.

can anyone tell me if there's any way to get back to original state(i.e, recover the files) or maybe reinstall php without compromising any apache/mysql configurations?

Comment: It would depend on which distro you are using

Comment: Since you tell us exactly nothing about your environment, the answer is: Restore from backup. In the time you wrote this, the restore could have been complete...

Comment: Hi I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: php version was 5.9 but now when i do php --version it gives me a long error..

Comment: Really sorry everyone to not properly frame the question and give appropriate info... (was really dissapointed with this problem :/ ) I'll try and update the question to make it more useful for everyone.. Thanks too.. for quick replies. SO rocks! and PS : my php ver : 5.5.9 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using ubuntu, what you can do is:

```
dpkg -l | grep php | cut -d' ' -f 3 | xargs apt-get install --reinstall
```

That will reinstall all packages that have php in their name, and return your .so files. You should run this command as a root user. If you run it as a regular user add sudo before apt-get.

Comment: wow!!! Thank you so very much...!! I really dont have the words enough!  That was simply put amazing!!

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: Happened to find myself in the same situation. While I knew it wasn't a disaster, this solution saved me quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer here: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04)

You can remove it:

```sh
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common
```

And reinstall it.

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```